# make.exe": *** [pf_hp.res] Error 1 in Eiffel C-compilation w/ mingw

Tags: compiler-errors, eiffel

I once had a .res Error and I solved it by deleting the .res file. But now I cannot see a pf_hp.res file in sources directory or EIFGENs :-(

I already installed estudio to a path without whitespace, to no avail.

What can I do to get C-compilation working, again?

Thanks in advance!
Gerrit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.res` files are generated from `.rc`. To make a clean test I would suggest to remove `EIFGENs` directory and `*.rc` files at the top of your project directory and recompile the project from scratch.